# Google Script Spreadsheet - Permission denied to use modification function

Tags: permissions, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm new in google script realisation.
I read all tutorials, and all the function that are made to get values from the spreadsheet work, but the one for the modification return errors. Everytime i use a fonction like setvalue, i get the message "permission denied to use setvalue". It's the same for create, etc...

Even when i make a copy-paste from the tutorials.

For example, this part of the runExample function returns me an error of permission.

```
for (var i = 0; i < departments.length; ++i) 
{
    var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(departments[i]) || ss.insertSheet(departments[i], ss.getSheets().length);
    sheet.clear();
    var headersRange = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, columnNames.length);
    headersRange.setValues([columnNames]);
    headersRange.setBackgroundColor(headerBackgroundColor);
    setRowsData(sheet, dataByDepartment[departments[i]]);
}
```

What can i do?
Is there somewhere i can set permission?

Thank you.
Emmanuel

Comment: Are you sure you are receiving an error? The first time you run a script that is using any Service that requires user authentication, you will be asked to authorize the script. Is that what you are seeing?

Answer (score 0):

The message is saying your script don't have permission to edit the Spreadsheet. To sort this problem you can either:

1. Go to Spreadsheet and click on 'Share' button (in the top right corner) and give EDIT PERMISSION to the people running the script.
2. If you don't want to give permission to other people, you can deploy your script with the following configuration:
   Execute App As: me (your_email@domain.com)
   Who has access to the App: Anyone

If you not sure how to deploy a Webb App, just follow this [tutorial](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/execution_web_apps)